# Native method - android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce

Tags: android, android-handler, anr

I have many ANR on Goole Play Console. While, the stack trace does not show any useful information. There are some snapshots of the problem.
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
Native method - android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce
Input dispatching timed out (No focused window)
```

The stack trace:

```
"main" tid=1 Native
  #00  pc 0x00000000000a6b6c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+12)
  #01  pc 0x0000000000017cbc  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+192)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000017b98  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+116)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000162854  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+48)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:335)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:161)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8022)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:942)

"Signal Catcher" tid=2 Runnable
  #00  pc 0x00000000006aac48  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+128)
  #01  pc 0x0000000000712e04  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+236)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000722050  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+208)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000374774  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+448)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000720660  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)+280)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000720054  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+292)
  #06  pc 0x00000000006f62d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+184)
  #07  pc 0x0000000000702a00  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::HandleSigQuit()+468)
  #08  pc 0x000000000057de10  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+268)
  #09  pc 0x00000000000ba598  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000053f3c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+68)

"perfetto_hprof_listener" tid=7 Native
  #00  pc 0x00000000000a58a8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (read+8)
  #01  pc 0x00000000000204e0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libperfetto_hprof.so (void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, ArtPlugin_Initialize::$_36> >(void*)+316)
  #02  pc 0x00000000000ba598  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000053f3c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+68)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" tid=8 Waiting
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:442)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:568)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:232)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:140)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)

"HeapTaskDaemon" tid=9 Waiting
  #00  pc 0x000000000004ea70  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+32)
  #01  pc 0x00000000003a8af4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+140)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000484480  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::GetTask(art::Thread*)+736)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000484154  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+32)
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks (Native method)
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:609)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:140)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)

"FinalizerDaemon" tid=10 Waiting
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:442)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:203)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:224)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:300)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:140)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)

"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" tid=11 Native
  #00  pc 0x000000000004ea70  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+32)
  #01  pc 0x00000000003a8af4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+140)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000629f68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPool::GetTask(art::Thread*)+120)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000629dc8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+136)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000629ca4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+164)
  #05  pc 0x00000000000ba598  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000053f3c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+68)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" tid=12 Waiting
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:442)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:568)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded (Daemons.java:385)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:365)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:140)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)

......
```

There are many `RecyclerView` to show data to user in my app. User can edit data in the item of the `RecyclerView`. Is the RecyclerView too busy to refresh? Or any other reason make this problem I have not found.

Does any one encounter this issue? And how can I solve this problem？

Thanks a lot.